# The variance of data set A is twice that of data set B; does this imply that the dispersion of data set A is twice that of data set B?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, standard-deviation

If the variance of data set A is 4, and the variance of data set B is 2, can we say that the data in set B is twice as dispersed as the data in set A? If the standard deviation of data set A is twice that of data set B, can it be understood that the dispersion of data set A is twice that of data set B？Why is there a need for standard deviation after having variance?can you give me a example to understand?